# Screened Poisson equation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

The screened Poisson equation, i.e.
$$
[\nabla^2−\lambda^2]\phi(r) =
−\psi(r),$$
occurs frequently in physics, including Yukawa theory of
mesons, in electric field screening in plasmas and nonlocal granular fluidity in granular flow.

Considering the homogeneous case, the equation becomes
$$
[\nabla^2−\lambda^2]\phi(r) = 0,
$$
which is equivalent to time-independent Klein-Gordon equation.

Are there any interesting applications on Riemannian manifolds for example in warped geometry?

Comment: You could ask what mesons, electric fields in plasmas, and granular flows do close to a black hole ... in principle, all these things appear in accretion disks, even the granular flows at a stretch ...

Comment: @Michael Engelhardt - Thank you for suggestions

Answer (score 1):

The screened Poisson equation on Riemannian manifolds is studied
in the context of object recognition for image processing, see [Screened Poisson Hyperfields for Shape Coding](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/140956117?journalCode=sjisbi) and [Interactive and Anisotropic Geometry Processing Using the Screened Poisson Equation](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/MyPapers/SIG11.pdf).

> A general framework is presented for performing geometry filtering
> through the solution of a screened Poisson equation. We show that this
> framework can be efficiently adapted to a changing Riemannian metric
> to support curvature-aware filtering and describe a parallel and
> streaming multigrid implementation for solving the system. We
> demonstrate the practicality of our approach by developing an interactive system for mesh editing that allows for exploration of a
> large family of curvature-guided, anisotropic filters.

Comment: Thank you very much